# Can jQuery load separate DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Is it possible with javascript, to load a string as DOM so that jquery operations[1] can be performed on it? And can DOMs be loaded concurrently?

Is that what `$.parseHTML(html)` does?

If so, how would I access the returned DOM?

What I'm trying to do is, use ajax to return html strings of other webpages, concurrently load them into DOMs, perform selections and copy desired elements to the original document

[1] Operations like selecting elements and modifying attributes.

Comment: Yes you can, why not just try it and see ?

Comment: just wrap response in `$()` can use any methods on it

Answer (score 2):

```
var dom = $(html);
```

will set `dom` to a jQuery object containing DOM of the HTML. You can then do operations like

```
dom.find("selector").append("<div>");
```

to modify it.

`$.parseHTML` is similar, but it returns an array of DOM elements, not a jQuery object. So you can't use jQuery methods on it, you have to use regular DOM methods. Of course, you can wrap any or all of these in jQuery objects by calling `$(...)` on them.